# Is it possible to connect the raspberry pi 4 to a wifi enabled projector (supporting miracast / airplay) without using a HDMI cable

Tags: raspbian, display, wireless

I have a rpi4 (4gb) currently loaded with raspberry pi os.
The rpi4 is connected to my wireless network using (wlan0) and assigned a reserved ip address, the audio is connected to my soundbar using bluetooth.

I have a wifi enabled projector (supporting airplay/miracast) which is also connected to my wireless network and assigned its own ip address.

What i want to do is connect the display (audio not required) of rpi4 to the projector using (airplay/miracast) instead of the HDMI cable.  I have purchased a separate wireless usb dongle which should provide the rpi4 with a wlan1 if needed.

Is what i want to do possible?

I have searched and found a GitHub project called miraclecast, which I have successfully compiled however it reports and error which i have raised as an issue with the author.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Does the projector support displaying network video streams?

Comment: unfortunately no.